# Template path hints are not displaying on front end, I tried in default and developer mode

Tags: magento2.3.5-p1, debug, paths, template-hints

Template hints are not displaying in both developer and default mode. I am using magento 2.3.5 p1
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable/disable path hints via CLI:

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```

Please don't forget to flush cache after enabling path hints in Admin Panel or via CLI:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the value of parameter_value in the url with  `?templatehints=[parameter_value]`, in your case the value of parameter_value is magento so is `?templatehints=magento`. If you don't want to pass the variable in the url, erase the value magento of the parameter_value and leave it  empty, and without pass the parameter you will see the template hints.

Works on Magento 2.4.2